# Performing a unitroot test on unbalanced panel data using purtest error

Tags: r, plm

I am attempting to perform a unit root test on my unbalanced panel data using the command from the plm package:

```
UR <- purtest(All, test="ips",exo="trend",lags="AIC",pmax=5)
```

and getting the error:

`Error in object[2:length(object)] - object[1:(length(object)-1)]: non-numeric argument to binary operator.`

Clearly the error consists in a variable that's supposed to be numeric being text.

The data set is set up as `Country Name`, `Year`, `Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3`, `Q4`, `Q5` with the `Q`'s being time varying variables and all of them except the `Country Name` being defined as numeric.

If more information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Or it could be that you have `NA`s in one or more of your columns.  Or maybe you need to exclude `Country Name` (and `Year`?) from the data frame before passing it to `purtest`?

Comment: Is `All` a data frame? Than it should be in a specific format for only one variable (individuals in colums). Likely, `All` contains all the variables you mentioned. Have a look at the examples in `?purtest`, you want to pass a single variable.